# KDE Hardware Detection is not running

Tags: services, kde

Some time ago my Kubuntu stopped displaying USB mass storage devices in the system tray.

If I go into `Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Service Manager`, the "Hardware Detection" service is "Not Running" and I assume this is the reason.

I can't see how to start it. I can't manipulate the entry in the Load-on-Demand window, and it isn't listed with the checkboxes in the Startup Services window.

How can I make this service start up automatically?

Comment: Which OS? Are you running udev? ps ax | grep udev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently if the Device Notifier is removed from the tray, device notifications elsewhere (e.g. Dolphin) can stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Go into /etc/udev/rules.d, delete the 70-persistent-net.rules file, reboot. It should work now.